# Retrieve results from a table based on conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a query with SQL as it needs an expertise. I have two tables Table A and B. Now I need to retrieve results from table 1 based on some conditions and i also need to retrieve results from table 1 based on results from table 2.

I want to achieve

```
Select * from table1 where author ="xyz") + select * from table1 where id=""

--->id = select post_ID from table2 where author = "abc"
```

So the ID values of table1 matches the post_ID values of table 2

Comment: Look up how to do joins. When stating you have two tables A & B its consistent if the question uses those. Don't do stored procedures. Its not necessary or sane.

Comment: This is a problem simple enough that don't need an expertise. Try learn some basic about SQL and write your own query for this. Your problem only need an `AND/ OR` logic to combine 2 conditions, and an `EXISTS` or `IN` or `JOIN` statement to match `a.id` with `b.post_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OR` condition

```
          select t1.* from table1 t1 where author ='xyz'
         or exists ( select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.post_ID=t1.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `UNION` to merge the results and `IN` to compare with post_ID value of table 2. Below code might help you.

```
Select * from table1 where author ="xyz" 
UNION 
select * from table1 where id  IN (select post_ID from table2 where author = "abc")
```